# Codeigniter 2 on IIS with web.config file

Tags: php, iis, codeigniter, web-config, codeigniter-2

I have a codeigniter app working fine locally with WAMP. However, I am having trouble getting it to work on an IIS server. Please note that I do not want to enable query strings.

Here is what I currently have in my web.config file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Clean URL" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This causes the main page to load properly: www.website.com/policies

However, when I click on an item to go to: www.website.com/policies/policy/view/31

The proper page is not displayed. The main page continues to be displayed.

The controller is Policy and the function is view(). The Codeigniter files are in a policies/ folder on the server.

I think the problem may be with my web.config file. The Config file's $config['base_url'] is dynamically calculated and is the correct one. The Config file's $config['index_page'] is blank. What do you think is causing this problem?

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Having done <?php phpinfo(); ?> on the server, it looks like URL Rewriter is set up. Here is the info for it:

_SERVER["IIS_UrlRewriteModule"] 7.1.0761.0

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Have you look at the example in the CI forums?

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/91954

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Rewrite to index.php">
                    <match url="index.php|robots.txt|images|test.php" />
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Rewrite CI Index">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|htm|html" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks Jakub. I just wanted to share the solution to my problem. Inside the config.php file, the $config['uri_protocol'] was set to 'QUERY_STRING'. I changed it to $config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO'. Then, I changed the web.config rule to:

<rule name="MyRule">
      <match url="^(.*)$" />
       <conditions>
             <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
             <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
 </rule>

Comment: @stevetronix Thanks that did the magic. you saved my 10ks of minutes.

Comment: Actually that negate match pattern provided will match those strings anywhere in the request, which you probably don't want. A correct regex for static files with those extensions is: `pattern="^.+\.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|htm|html|eot|woff|ttf|svg|txt)$" negate="true"`

Comment: For CI4, put this inside the public folder and it will work just fine

Answer (score 5):

i have placed the following web.config code in the root and it worked perfectly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <system.webServer>
            <rewrite>
                <rules>
                    <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                            <add input="{URL}" pattern="^system.*" ignoreCase="false" />
                        </conditions>
                        <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?{R:1}" />
                    </rule>
                    <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                            <add input="{R:1}" pattern="^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        </conditions>
                        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?{R:1}" />
                    </rule>
                </rules>
            </rewrite>
        </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

Answer (score 3):

It turns out I didn't have Rewrite installed.  This did the trick:

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

I'm not sure if codeigniter's error page may have masked the error somewhat, because I couldn't determine that it wasn't installed from the browser's error screen.  Also Event Viewer, IIS logs, and PHP logs all were not helpful for this situation.

Answer (score 3):

Okay!

Recently I had made an admin control panel with CI and grocery crud . It was working great with WAMP on my local server with a pretty URL and redirection. I was talking about the CI is the best framework I had ever work. It’s so easy to use and very well documented Cheers!! to CodeIgniter.

But when I had to move my admin panel on IIS server 7.XX then seems my nightmare starts. Everything was stopping No redirection, No error display nothing was happening. I was so scared of why it’s happening. I dig Google, stack overflow, CI forum for almost 6 hours. I didn't receive anything from anywhere. I was so sad :(

I can’t think about what I should do. Then, I have made myself cool and calm and start to review everything step by step that is here:

```
1.    Set error reporting on
2.    Check PHP info
3.    Check redirect/rewrite
4.    Check MySQL/MySQLi extension loaded or not in IIS server
5.    Converted my .htaccess file rule with web.config rule (Really helped me)
6.    Put web.config file in the main directory (CI working folder) not in the root folder
```

[How to convert .htaccess in web.config?](http://blogs.iis.net/ruslany/archive/2008/09/11/url-rewrite-module-go-live-release.aspx)

Then, I found that everything is correct except ‘mysqli’ extension was not loaded on IIS Server and my database config credentials were wrong. Then I made changes in php.ini (check’ phpinfo()’ to find php.ini path on IIS Server) line no 881 with uncomment extension=php_mysqli.dll.

Here is my CI config settings:

```
$config['base_url']    = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol']    = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

After that, reopen my CI admin panel now!!!!!! Everything wow!! wow!! working like charm :) he he he….
I was so happy :) :)

Here is my web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1">
                    <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{URL}" redirectType="Found" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1-1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^system.*" ignoreCase="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^application.*" ignoreCase="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Here is my pretty URL type

```
https://mysite.abc.com/administrator/admin/showUsers

the administrator is my  admin folder

admin is my controller

and showUsers in my controller method
```

Hope my bad experience will help somebody :)

Answer (score 1):

```
You can like this,
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
          </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```