# setting up laravel on IIS7

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, iis-7, virtualhost, laravel

I want to set up my `IIS7` server in order to let it works with a web application written in `laravel` (php framework).

I found something similar for `CI` ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408111/codeigniter-2-on-iis-with-web-config-file))

but it doesn't work on `laravel` (of course I removed the `index.php` redirection).

actually only home page works (`www.mysite.com/public`)

anybody uses/d `IIS7` with Laravel?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

I created the `web.config` file in root folder inside `<configuration></configuration>`:

```
<system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <clear />
            <add value="index.php" />
            <add value="default.aspx" />
            <add value="Default.htm" />
            <add value="Default.asp" />
            <add value="index.htm" />
            <add value="index.html" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Execute, Script" />
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="public/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

then copy the `index.php` file of the public folder into the root folder of the project modifying the `../paths.php` into `paths.php` as [this](http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=16813) guide says

now everything works perfectly

Answer (score 4):

I used the code below, redirect to  `index.php/{R:1}` rather than `public/{R:1}`  Works straight out of the box then with no path changes.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 3):

Check your Handler Mappings in IIS:

1. launch IIS
2. click on your site
3. go on 'handler mappings' (in IIS block)
4. Search for Path PHP, Name = PHPxx_via_FastCGI (xx = php version)
5. Double click it, click on request restrictions and click on tab 'Verb's where you choose All verbs. This will fix it :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here is my working file, with two rules: (web site is pointing to public folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="RewriteRequestsToPublic">
          <match url="^(.*)$" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:0}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me! Also, I had to move index.php to the root path.

Answer (score 3):

Just got it working after long hours of google and testing. Here is my steps:

laravel5 with IIS 8.5

1. install [window platform installer](http://www.microsoft.com/WEB/downloads/platform.aspx)
2. install php-5.6 with window platform installer
3. install php-manager for IIS with window platform installer (optional)
4. install [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 (version x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679)
   Without this, FastCgi process excited unexpected (php_info() will not works)
5. install composer.exe
6. export composer vendor bin path to path
   `set PATH=%PATH%;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin`
7. run `composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"`
8. run `lavarel new app`
9. create new application in IIS and point to `<app>/public`

That's it, Happy Lavarel!

Reference: http://alvarotrigo.com/blog/installing-laravel-4-in-windows-7-with-iis7/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to retrieve your $_GET variables do not use:

`<match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />`

Instead use:

`<match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I fixed it. 
open the config file, if the following mapping not exists, put these lines under

```
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
      </rule>
      <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

To install `IIS` on your windows, goto `control panel -> uninstall programs` and press `Turn Off Windows Features On/Off` link and click `IIS` and select `CGI` option.

[image]

Download `Web Platform Installer` from internet `install PHP and SQL drivers for IIS`

Open `IIS` from programs add Website. and for public folder point point to `Public` folder in the laravel/lumen project.

for Laravel and Lumen projects. Create project from composer in any accessible folder. got to `public` folder in the folder structure and create `web.config` file with below contents i obtained this from laracasts

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
          <rules>
            <rule name="Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
              <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
              <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```