# htaccess file issue in Laravel 5 using IIS

Tags: php, .htaccess, iis, web-config, laravel-5

I am configuring Laravel 5 on IIS. Whenever I am trying to access any URL it gives 404 error. There is some issue with `.htaccess` file so I am using `web.config` file. Here is my `web.config` file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Laravel4" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And here is my `.htaccess` file code:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have placed this file on my root folder (public folder) but it's still not working. Is there any solutions?

Comment: Is that your `.htaccess` file ?

Comment: No, this is my web.config file.

Comment: Can you show your `.htaccess` file ?

Comment: Here is my .htaccess file code`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
`

Comment: Please update it in your question

Comment: Isn't [this](https://eval.in/369557) your `.htaccess` ?

Comment: No,this is my htaccess file code.

Comment: Can you try with the `.htaccess ` that i have posted ?

Comment: I can't se your posted .htaccess file brother. Please help me for this one.

Comment: It should be in this location https://eval.in/369557

Comment: I have checked it but isn't same like the file that i have posted?

Comment: Ah, sorry, i didn't noted it.. can you do this change .. just a try.. Just move the .htaccess to the root folder or your laravel project and rename the server.php to index.php ?

Comment: I think the htaccess file is not work in IIS server. We have to use web.config file for url rewrite perpose.

Comment: Ah, are you sure,, because i also hosted few of my project in IIS Server and it didn't makes me trouble. But i felt one problem.. I always wanted to use `project/public/index.php`

Comment: Yes, i have researched on that and i found this one solution. We have to use web.config file for url rewriting in IIS Server.

Comment: It appears your `web.config` file is correct. Can you confirm that your `index.php` and `web.config` files are in the same directory? Also, is your document root set to the `public` folder? Also, please refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381950/setting-up-laravel-on-iis7) for further help.

Comment: yes ,index.php and web.config file are in the same directory. And how do i check that the document root is set to the public folder?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution.

If you have tried all the possible things to resolve .htaccess or web.config file issue and again it's not working than uninstall URL Rewrite module from your server's control panel and reinstall it. It will definitely work. And make sure you have installed `URL Rewrite 2.0` for `IIS 7`.

Comment: this fix mine too. i was shocked that it was solved with a simple solution as this. thank you [+1]