# How to use Ajax call to a specific controller action?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I am trying to use `Ajax` to reload data from a database. However, the `Ajax` doesn't call the controller action that I specified in the `url:`. Here is my `Ajax` code:

```
function selectFieldChanged(id){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: Routing.generate('demo_ajax'),
        data: id,
        success: function(){
            alert("Success");
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert('Error : ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var id = $(this).val();
    $('#form_patient').change(function(){selectFieldChanged(id)});
});
```

The `routing.xml` :

```
demo_ajax:
    pattern: /ajax/patient
    defaults: { _controller: DemoBundle:Default:index}
    options:
        expose: true
```

So, I tried to simply echo the value out in the `indexAction` to see whether it is called or not.

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{   
        if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
            echo "xmlHttpRequest is called";
        }
        if($request->getMethod()=='POST'){
            echo 'POST is called';
        }
}
```

However, I didn't get anything from the `indexAction` but I got the alert message, `` `Success ``, from my `Ajax` What did I do wrong?

Comment: If you change Routing.generate('demo_ajax') by the real url ?

Comment: So what is the output of `console.log(Routing.generate('demo_ajax'));` if you call it on the first line of `selectFieldChanged()`?

Comment: data: id is wrong, you need to use data as object as `data: {id: id}`

Comment: The result of `console.log(Routing.generate('demo_ajax'))` is `/app_dev.php/ajax/patient `

Comment: Is that the expected URL?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I think so. That what I specified in the `routing.xml`.

Comment: So if you visit `www.yourwebsite.com/app_dev.php/ajax/patient` in your web browser then do you arrive at the correct place?

Comment: Please see my comment on this SO question to properly debug AJAX calls: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21533285/why-the-ajax-script-is-not-running-on-iis-7-5-win-2008-r2-server#comment32640491_21533285

Comment: I answered it in a more readable format as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21617685/2191572

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The success callback receives data from your server so a variable must be declared to capture it:

```
success: function(data){ // <-----

    console.log(data);

    alert("Success");

},
```

Comment: Ok. I did as you mentioned in the comment and also printed it out. I can see that the response data is passed from the `indexAction` to the `Ajax` as well. However, I don't quite understand why the `echo` function didn't be compiled.

Comment: You have 2 separate `if()` statements in your PHP so `$request->isXmlHttpRequest()` is returning FALSE and `$request->getMethod()` is not POST. Comment out everything inside `indexAction()` and simply execute this `echo $request->getMethod();`

Comment: I got an alert message -  `Error : SyntaxError: Unexpected token P`.

Comment: I have never seen this before `public function indexAction(Request $request)`. Can you explain what it is doing? Specifically the `(Request $request)` portion

Comment: I assume he is using __symfony__ framework, where you can see this kind of syntax.

Comment: `Request $request` is used to get the `Request object` in symfony2. Now, it showed up the `POST` message. I don't know what was the problem. I tried to undo the code to the beginning and it still worked. The cause of problem may occur because of `cache`.

Comment: Thanks @code-jaff! LVarayut: if you are experiencing AJAX cache issues then you can try putting `cache: false,` in your AJAX options.

Comment: But if this is a Symphony cache issue then unfortunately I am not familiar with Symphony