# Submitting php file without refreshing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to make a single php form to make some calculations, however when pressing the submit button nothing happens.

I am trying to use ajaxForm to do this

**Code:**

```
<?php

  if(isset($_POST['submit'], $_POST['v'], $_POST['e'], $_POST['ei'])){
$v = $_POST['v']; //Dyrets vægt
$v = pow($v, 0.75);
$s = (int)$_POST['s']; //Stofskifte
$e = (int)$_POST['e']; //Energibehov
$ei = (int)$_POST['ei']; //Energiindhold i foder

$vaegt = ($v);
$stofskift = round($vaegt * $s, 2);
$de = $stofskift * $e;
$eif = round($de / $ei * 100, 2);
$result = round($eif * 4.2, 2);

$arr = array( 'testDiv' => $result );
  echo json_encode( $arr );

 exit;
};

//$string = '(((('.$v.')*'.$s.')*'.$e.')/'.$ei.' * 100) * 4,2';

?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Hej</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsFile.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="" class="ajaxForm" >
<label for="vaegt">Weight</label><br>
<input type="text" name="v" id="v" placeholder="Weight"><br>
<label for="type">Art</label><br>
<select size="7" name="s" id="s"> 
  <option value="70" >Fugl</option>
</select><br><br>
<label for="str">Størrelse</label><br>
<select size="7" name="e" id="e"> 
  <option value="1.25" >Absolut</option>
</select><br><br>

<label for="foder">Foder</label><br>
<select size="4" name="ei" id="ei"> 
  <option value="60" >Plante</option>
</select><br><br>

<input type="submit" value="Udregn" name="submit" class="ajaxSubmit"/>

</form>

<div id="testDiv">result here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**jsFile.js:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('.ajaxform').submit( function() {

        $.ajax({
            url     : $(this).attr('action'),
            type    : $(this).attr('method'),
            dataType: 'json',
            data    : $(this).serialize(),
            success : function( data ) {
                        for(var id in data) {
                            jQuery('#' + id).html( data[id] );
                        }
                      }
        });

        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?   I'm not lazy but... Maybe a JS fiddle or something if you want us to debug it?

Comment: Is the `success` event ever being called?

Comment: No I am not getting any errors @ficuscr

Comment: You aren't exiting() from the php code after handling the json stuff, so your html form becomes part of the ajax response, leading to corrupted json, killing the rest of your ajax handler. Check your browser's debug console (shift-ctrl-J) in firefox, and you'll probably see various json-related errors.

Comment: Try changing `echo json_encode( $arr );` to `die( json_encode( $arr ) );`.

Comment: @NathanDawson it doesnt work

Comment: @MarcB i tried to exit after echo json_encode( $arr ); but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you check what the HTTP response is from PHP?  There might be PHP errors.

Comment: check for any OTHER output from your function as well. you're checking if 'submit' and 'v' are set, but if 's', 'e', and 'ei' aren't you're going to get php warnings mixed into the output.

Comment: @MarcB I updated the code and included a exit;(edited code here as well) but it still does not change <div id="testDiv">result here</div>

Comment: Debug, debug, debug, debug, and debug! http://stackoverflow.com/a/21617685/2191572

Comment: Solved!  See `Problem #2` in my edits.  I found this by putting all the files on my own server and testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem #1:**

In your `if` statement that handles a POST request, you output a bunch of JSON.  But you forgot to exit output when you're done.  So, your output looks like:

```
{"a":"b","c":"d"/* more json here*/}
<html>
<head>
/* more html here */
```

Which, obviously is not valid JSON.  jQuery, if the response is not real JSON, calls the `error` method instead of the `success` method.

To fix the problem, add this line before the end of your PHP `if` statement:

```
exit;
```

That will quit the PHP script before all of the HTML is outputted.

**Problem #2:**

`$(this).serialize()` only grabs inputs that have values.  This excludes buttons.  So, unlike a normal form submit, the `submit` button is not included in the POST request.  This is causing your first `if` statement to evaluate to false.

So, just remove the first of the nestled `if` statements (the `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` one) and it will work correctly.

Comment: Hope OP takes away soemthing from the advice on debugging in the browser if [nothing else](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_D_Z-D2tzi14/S8TRIo4br3I/AAAAAAAACv4/Zh7_GcMlRKo/s400/ALOT.png).