# Control Not going to the Controller

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i am using codeigniter. I have set a form validation via jquery and after validation the data /control is not moving on to the Controller.
Here is my jquery code

```
var data1 = {               
                username:$("#username").val(),
                password:$("#password").val()           
                }


            $.ajax({

                    type:'POST',
                    url:base_url+"site/chk_info",


                    data:data1,

                    success: function (response){

                            alert (response);

                        },

                    error:function (){
alert ("Sorry we are getting problems plz try again latter");

                        }

                    });  // end ajax
```

Here is my controller method.

```
public function chk_info(){

        return true;    

    }
```

The problem is in jquery the controll in not entering into the success function it always getting into the error function.

Comment: Check the XHR request in your console.

Comment: **[Debug the AJAX request](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21617685/2191572)**

Comment: Is base_url set in javascript?

Comment: @Lee Salminen yes i have set that base_url

Answer (score 0):

`chk_info()` is only returning `true` IF PHP was listening and acting upon it.

You should be echo-ing `true` like this instead:

```
public function chk_info(){
    echo 'true';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this i think its url problem

```
 $.ajax({

        type:'POST',
        url:'<?php echo base_url() ?>site/chk_info',
        data:data1,
         success: function (response){
                  alert (response);
                     },

                    error:function (){
alert ("Sorry we are getting problems plz try again latter");

                        }

                    });
```