# Getting Data back from Python with Cherrypy and jQuery/AJAX

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, cherrypy

Unfortunately i dont get ajax to work properly with cherrypy.
Here is my python code:

```
from mako.template import Template
from mako.lookup import TemplateLookup
import cherrypy
import os
import json

CURDIR = os.getcwd()

cherrypy.config.update({
    "tools.staticdir.root" : CURDIR,
    "tools.staticdir.dir" : "static",
    "tools.staticdir.on" : True
    })

# Loopuoobjekt für die Templates
tmplLookup = TemplateLookup(directories=['templates'])
# Liefert das Gerenderte Template zurück
def serve_template(templatename, **tmpl_vars):
    template = tmplLookup.get_template(templatename)
    return template.render(**tmpl_vars)

class Root(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return serve_template("index.html")

    @cherrypy.expose
        def switch(self, id):
        print("Licht nr {} wurde geschaltet".format(id))
        cherrypy.response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
        return json.dumps({"text" : "schalter {} ".format(id)})

cherrypy.quickstart(Root())
```

and Here is my html template:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "switch",
                type: "POST",
                data: {id: $(this).attr('id')},
                succes: function(response) {
                    $("#test").html(response);
                } 
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hallo Haus!</h1>
    <button id=1>Licht 1</button> </br>
    <button id=2>Licht 2</button> </br>
    <button id=3>Licht 3</button> </br>
    <button id=4>Licht 4</button>

    <div id=test></div>

</body>
</html>
```

If i press one of those 4 buttons i get the right id printed in my console.
The above example

```
return json.dumps({"text" : "schalter {} ".format(id)})
```

is written on the most toturials i found, but unfortunately this gives me an error:

```
[09/Apr/2014:15:36:57] HTTP Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\cherrypy-3.2.4-py3.3.egg\cherrypy\_cprequ
est.py", line 656, in respond
    response.body = self.handler()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\cherrypy-3.2.4-py3.3.egg\cherrypy\_cprequ
est.py", line 814, in __set__
raise ValueError(self.unicode_err)
ValueError: Page handlers MUST return bytes. Use tools.encode if you wish to re
turn unicode.
```

So the data is succesfully send to cherrypy, but i did not get it back.
Any help how to get this to work?

Comment: I do not know `Python` nor `cherrypy` but I certainly hope you use the **[Network Tab](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21617685/2191572)** for debugging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding @cherrypy.tools.json_out() to your switch handler...

```
import cherrypy
import os
import json

CURDIR = os.getcwd()

cherrypy.config.update({
    "tools.staticdir.dir" : CURDIR,
    "tools.staticdir.on" : True
    })

# Loopuoobjekt für die Templates

# Liefert das Gerenderte Template zurück
class Root(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return """<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "switch",
            type: "POST",
            data: {id: $(this).attr('id')},
            success: function(response) {
                alert(response);
                $("#test").html(response);
            } 
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hallo Haus!</h1>
    <button id=1>Licht 1</button> </br>
    <button id=2>Licht 2</button> </br>
    <button id=3>Licht 3</button> </br>
    <button id=4>Licht 4</button>

    <div id=test></div>

</body>
</html>"""

    @cherrypy.expose
    @cherrypy.tools.json_out()
    def switch(self, id):
        print("Licht nr {} wurde geschaltet".format(id))
        return json.dumps({"text" : "schalter {} ".format(id)})

cherrypy.quickstart(Root())
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also, you misspelled success in your ajax function.

Comment: Ok, i got the @cherrypy.tools.json_out() in my code and return the dictionary directly, now im getting another error: TypeError: Chunk '{' is not of type 'bytes'. this is how i return my response: return {"text" : "schalter {} ".format(id)

Comment: well you'll still have to keep using json.dumps... return json.dumps({"text" : "schalter {} ".format(id)})

Comment: it now ends in TypeError: Chunk '"{\\"text\\": \\"schalter 4 \\"}"' is not of type 'bytes'.

Comment: hmmm.  what version of python are you using?  i'm on 3.2 and it's running correctly for me.  I'll edit my answer with the code that's working.

Comment: Ok, i copied your whole code above, no im  getting this error again: File "C:\python33\lib\site-packages\cherrypy-3.2.4-py3.3.egg\cherrypy\_cprequest.py", line 892, in collapse_body
    raise TypeError("Chunk %s is not of type 'bytes'." % repr(chunk))
TypeError: Chunk '{' is not of type 'bytes'.

Comment: weird... it runs for me under python 3.3.3 as well.  I'm also on cherrypy 3.2.4 too.  Trying setting "tools.encode.encoding": "utf8", in your config update statement.

Comment: and again: TypeError: Chunk '{' is not of type 'bytes'.
I dont understand what could cause this problem...

Comment: Ok, i tried your solution on my linux machine and it worked perfectly, thanks you for you patience!