# Posting json with ajax issue

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, cherrypy

I have the following code, which always generate 404 error (not found):

```
data = Object {a: "500000", b: "4"}
postJson(data);


function postJson(data){
    $.ajax({
                url: '/url/postJson',
                type: 'POST',
                data: data, //also tried "JSON.stringify(data)"
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('error')
                }
            });
}
```

On the server side:

```
@cherrypy.expose
def postJson(self, data):
    print data //just for the test
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Is the URL correct? Going on the name of the function, shouldn't it be `/url/postJson`?

Comment: @BrianRay I fixed it. It was a typo. These are not the real names. Anyway, the real URL is correct. It was the first thing i've checked.

Comment: Well, it has something to do with the URL. That's the only way you're going to get a 404. However, without knowing the directory structure, there's not much more I can do to help.

Comment: When i try browse directly to this URL, i get `HTTPError: (404, 'Missing parameters: data')` so i guess that the URL is not the issue.

Comment: Browser used GET method, not POST.

Comment: To check the URL by POST using CURL, for example.

Comment: @StanZeez i tried to use CURL as you posted below and got `HTTPError: (404, 'Missing parameters: data')`. Any idea why?

Comment: I've edited my post and added the server side function.

Comment: May be argument 'data' should be in sending data? (--data '{"data": "something", a: "500000", b: "4"}'). Do you have any specification for request to server?

Comment: @StanZeez I don't have any specification. I just need to post json on this URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going by the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22964527/getting-data-back-from-python-with-cherrypy-and-jquery-ajax#answer-22965076), it looks like your JSON formatting needs to be updated. Try this.

```
data = {data: {a: "500000", b: "4"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

404 is state from server side.
For checking exists and access your url try to curl:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{a: "500000", b: "4"}' http://url/portJson
```

My often used 100% working function for POST Django backend (Im not set 'contentType' and 'dataType', but I set 'X-CSRFToken'):

```
function sendAjaxRequest(url, data, done, always, fail, reqType, timeout) {
    var _done = function() {};
    var _always = function() {};
    var _fail = function(jqXHR,status,err){
        alert('Error (' + status + '): ' + err + '\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
    }
    var _reqType ='POST'
    var _timeout = 60000;

    if (typeof done !== 'undefined') _done = done;
    if (typeof always !== 'undefined') _always = always;
    if (typeof fail !== 'undefined') _fail = fail;
    if (typeof reqType !== 'undefined') _reqType = reqType;
    if (typeof timeout !== 'undefined') _timeout = timeout;

    var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken');

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        headers:{ 'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken },
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        type: _reqType,
        timeout: _timeout
    }).done(_done).always(_always).fail(_fail);
};
```

using:

```
var data = {'a': "5000", 'b': "4"};

sendAjaxRequest(
    "/my/url/",
    data,
    function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {// done
       // do work
    }, undefined, undefined, 'POST'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

On the server change:

```
@cherrypy.expose
def postJson(self, data):
    print data //just for the test
```

to:

```
@cherrypy.expose
@cherrypy.tools.json_in
def postJson(self):
    data = cherrypy.request.json
    print data //just for the test
```