# Is there a way to debug failed AJAX requests? Or why is mine failing?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

The following `alert`s me with "got an error, bro" when I click one of the `button`s of class `member-update-button`, i.e. the `error` callback function is getting invoked. Any idea why? There are no errors being printed to the console. In the future, how can I debug to find the reason myself? How can I get more information about why it failed?

**HTML:**

```
    <form method="POST" action="../wp-content/themes/allytics_theme/management/member_update.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="modal fade" id="member-modal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                                <h2></h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                                Full name:
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
                                <input type="text" name="fullname" value=""> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                                Title:
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
                                <input type="text" name="title" value="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                                Bio (approx 150 chars):
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
                                <input type="textarea" name="bio" value=""> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                                Sort order:
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
                                <input type="textarea" name="sord" value=""> 
                            </div>                          
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                                Pic: 
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
                                <input type="file" name="pic">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                                <!-- empty space -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
                                <button type="button" class="member-update-button wp-core-ui button-primary" id="remv-btn">Remove</button>
                                <button type="button" class="member-update-button wp-core-ui button-primary">Add</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="memberAction" value="" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
        jQuery('.member-update-button').click( function() {
                var parentForm = jQuery(this).closest('form');
                var formUrl = parentForm.attr('action');
                var formMethod = parentForm.attr('method');
                var postData = parentForm.serializeArray();
                jQuery.ajax(
                    {
                        url: formUrl,
                        type: formMethod,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: postData,
                        success: function(retmsg)
                        {
                            alert(retmsg); // test for now
                        }, 
                        error: function ( )
                        {
                            alert("got an error, bro"); // test for now
                        }
                    }
                );
        } );
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
    echo json_encode("here's the return message");
?>
```

Comment: Answering your first question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21533285/why-the-ajax-script-is-not-running-on-iis-7-5-win-2008-r2-server/21617685#21617685 will greatly aid you in figuring out your second question.

Comment: ^ you can set breakpoints and step thru code, watch, etc.  All the usual JIT stuff.

Comment: Thanks, @MonkeyZeus. I identified my problem and fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
echo json_encode(array("here's the return message"));
```

Comment: Please consider adding at least some words to explain to the OP and future reader why and how this does answer the question.