# WordPress AJAX call not executing PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to do a custom AJAX action on WordPress but it isn't working. I have the following form:

```
<form method='post' name='form-bid-<?php echo get_the_ID() ?>' class="bid-form">
    <input type='submit' name='<?php echo get_the_ID()?>' value='Licitar' class='bidvalue'>
    <?php wp_nonce_field('ajax-bid-nonce', $post->ID); ?>
</form>
```

The form is this way because it's generated inside a loop, one for every post on the site, therefore I use the post ID as the unique name for the input.

Then, I capture the form submit on a custom JavaScript file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

// Perform AJAX bid on form submit
$('form.bid-form').on('submit', function(e) {

    var action = 'ajaxbid';
    var auction_id = e.target.name.substring('form-bid-'.length);
    var security_container = "#".concat(auction_id);
    var security = $(security_container).val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: ajax_bid_object.ajaxurl,

        data: { 
            'action': action,
            'id': auction_id,
            'security': security
        },

        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});

});
```

This part works, and it prints 0 on the console upon success.

Finally, I have a PHP file where I register the script and have the function I want to call upon the form submission:

```
function ajax_bid_init() {
    wp_register_script('ajax-bid-script', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/ajax-bid-script.js', array('jquery') ); 
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax-bid-script');

    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-bid-script', 'ajax_bid_object', array( 
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
    ));

    // Enable the user with no privileges to run ajax_bid() in AJAX
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxbid', 'ajax_bid' );
}

add_action('init', 'ajax_bid_init');

function ajax_bid() {
    // First check the nonce, if it fails the function will break
    check_ajax_referer( 'ajax-bid-nonce', 'security');
    echo json_encode(array('message'=>__('SUCCESS')));  
    die();
}
```

For now, all I wanted was the function to return that array and display it on console. However, the code never seems to run through here, and the AJAX response is always 0.

I have done a quite similar approach to both login and registration on the website and they both work. I've compared the 3 endless times and I cannot seem to find what I'm missing here.

Comment: Try checking out the Network tab for clues: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21617685/2191572

Comment: What is `ajax_bid_object.ajaxurl` I do not see it within the scope of `jQuery(document).ready(function($) { /* I don't see it in here :( */ });`

Comment: The network tab shows everything working fine and the form data contains exactly what I want. The `ajax_bid_object` is the name of the variable which contains the data of the script (see [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)).

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue! I forgot to mention I was trying to do this with a logged user, so the problem was this line:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxbid', 'ajax_bid' );
```

It should be this instead:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajaxbid', 'ajax_bid' );
```

I copied the first from my login and register forms, which made sense to be only available for non-logged users. The bids however are the exact opposite.

Just for future reference, you can register both (`wp_ajax` and `wp_ajax_nopriv`) for the same function if you want it to be executable for both logged and non-logged users.