# How to return an error status on an ajax call in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have this script code and it works perfectly,

**CODE**

```
<script>
    function ajob(){
        var a3=a.value
        var a4=b.value
        var a5=c.value
        if(a3!='' && a4!=''){
            $.ajax({
                type:"get",
                url:"addj.php?content=" + a3 + "," + a4 + "," + a5
            });
         lod();
        }else{alert('Fill all fields')}
    }
</script>

<form>
    <table>
        <tr><td>Job Name:</td>
            <td><input id="a" name="jname" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>Job Description:</td>
            <td><input id="b" name="jd" style="margin: 2px 0 2px 0;" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>Status:</td>
            <td>
                <select id="c" name="jstat" style="width:100%; height: 26px" >
                    <option>Active</option>
                    <option>Not Active</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

what i want to know is how can can i know if there is an error in my `addj.php` file? Here is my `addj.php`

**addj.php**

```
require 'con.php';
$pieces = explode(",", $_GET['content']);
$jname=$pieces[0];
$jd=$pieces[1];
$jstat=$pieces[2];
$query=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO job(job_name,job_desc,status) values('$jname','$jd','$jstat') ");
```

How do I return a failed status from my PHP code and how can I handle that error in my java script code?

Comment: You can make use of console to see any errors in AJAX or Javascript

Comment: Side note: this is not a good idea -> `$query=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO job(job_name,job_desc,status) values('$jname','$jd','$jstat') ");` SQL-injection prone.

Comment: Whatever you echoed in addj.php , will catch in ajax response, so echoed possible errors in addj.php file.

Comment: @SHAZ how can i make an ajax response?

Comment: @Rasclatt how can i make my `$query` good?

Comment: I think you can use the `mysqli_real_escape_string()` but the best is to look up bind and parametrized statements

Comment: @prettyme, using `succss:function(response){ alert(response); }`. And for better query use `PDO` instead of `mysqli_*`

Comment: @SHAZ I think PDO being better is a matter of opinion. I personally like PDO better and use it exclusively, but I don't know that it's better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use success or error callback function and output data to console.

```
function ajob(){
    var a3=a.value
    var a4=b.value
    var a5=c.value
    if(a3!='' && a4!=''){
        $.ajax({
            type:"get",
            url:"addj.php?content=" + a3 + "," + a4 + "," + a5,
            success: function(dataReturn, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                console.log(dataReturn);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
                console.log(textStatus,errorThrown);
            }
        });
     lod();
    }else{alert('Fill all fields')}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
            $.ajax({
                type:"get",
                url:"addj.php?content=" + a3 + "," + a4 + "," + a5,
                success: function(data) { alert("succsess") },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert(xhr.status + " : " + xhr.responseText);

                 }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the console of the browser. Try following link that has step by step.

[Why the Ajax script is not running on IIS 7.5 Win 2008 R2 server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21533285/why-the-ajax-script-is-not-running-on-iis-7-5-win-2008-r2-server/21617685#21617685)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to catch any ajax errors.

```
$.ajax({
  type:"get",
  url:"addj.php?content=" + a3 + "," + a4 + "," + a5
}).fail(function(error){
  alert(error);
});
```

Hope it helps.