# error in loader: JSON Parse error: Invalid number located in jquery

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble getting a page to load because the js loader is being effected by an error in query JSON parse.

This is the error in noted by Safari.

```
    error in loader: JSON Parse error: Invalid number at line 2618:       http://localhost:8888/iicode/jquery-1.11.2.min.js
```

here is a snippet of the code at line 2618, which has the asterix.

```
     var vc = m.now(), wc = /\?/, xc = /(,)|(\[|{)|(}|])|"(?:[^"\\\r\n]|\\["\\\/bfnrt]|\\u[\da-fA-F]{4})*"\s*:?|true|false|null|-?(?!0\d)\d+(?:\.\d+|)(?:[eE][+-]?\d+|)/g;
m.parseJSON = function(b) {
    if (a.JSON && a.JSON.parse)
        **return a.JSON.parse(b + "");**
    var c, d = null, e = m.trim(b + "");
    return e&&!m.trim(e.replace(xc, function(a, b, e, f) {
        return c && b && (d = 0), 0 === d ? a : (c = e || b, d+=!f-!e, "")
    })) ? Function("return " + e)() : m.error("Invalid JSON: " + b)
}, m.parseXML = function(b) {
    var c, d;
    if (!b || "string" != typeof b)
        return null;
    try {
        a.DOMParser ? (d = new DOMParser, c = d.parseFromString(b, "text/xml")) : (c = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM"), c.async = "false", c.loadXML(b))
    } catch (e) {
        c = void 0
    }
    return c && c.documentElement&&!c.getElementsByTagName("parsererror").length || m.error("Invalid XML: " + b), c
};
```

Here is the the first few lines of the js loader that the error is disabling, and I have no idea why. Safari highlighted the part that I asterix.

```
    (function(window, jQuery) {
var namespace = 'de.kubikfoto', engine = null, args = {}, jsonFiles = {}, xmlFiles = {}, filesToLoad = 1, oldloadXML = null, oldloadJSON = null;
function logerror(errortext) {
    if (typeof console === "object" && typeof console.error === "function") {
        **console.error("error in loader: " + errortext)**
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated my website is currently at a standstill.

As some have noted a potential problem with the Ajax, here is the call.

```
    the ajax call I found was this :   v[d](k[d]);
        if (i = Mc(Ic, k, b, v)) {
            v.readyState = 1, h && n.trigger("ajaxSend", [v, k]), k.async && k.timeout > 0 && (g = setTimeout(function() {
                v.abort("timeout")
            }, k.timeout));
            try {
                t = 1, i.send(r, x)
            } catch (w) {
                if (!(2 > t))
                    throw w;
                x( - 1, w)
            }
        } else 
            x( - 1, "No Transport");
        function x(a, b, c, d) {
            var j, r, s, u, w, x = b;
            2 !== t && (t = 2, g && clearTimeout(g), i = void 0, f = d || "", v.readyState = a > 0 ? 4 : 0, j = a >= 200 && 300 > a || 304 === a, c && (u = Oc(k, v, c)), u = Pc(k, u, v, j), j ? (k.ifModified && (w = v.getResponseHeader("Last-Modified"), w && (m.lastModified[e] = w), w = v.getResponseHeader("etag"), w && (m.etag[e] = w)), 204 === a || "HEAD" === k.type ? x = "nocontent" : 304 === a ? x = "notmodified" : (x = u.state, r = u.data, s = u.error, j=!s)) : (s = x, (a ||!x) && (x = "error", 0 > a && (a = 0))), v.status = a, v.statusText = (b || x) + "", j ? o.resolveWith(l, [r, x, v]) : o.rejectWith(l, [v, x, s]), v.statusCode(q), q = void 0, h && n.trigger(j ? "ajaxSuccess" : "ajaxError", [v, k, j ? r: s]), p.fireWith(l, [v, x]), h && (n.trigger("ajaxComplete", [v, k]), --m.active || m.event.trigger("ajaxStop")))
        }
```

Comment: Do you have an AJAX call that is returning badly formatted data?

Comment: where would be the best place to check?

Comment: In any AJAX calls that you have executing - use the network tab to see the responses. Or if you're using $.parseJSON anywhere, check that too

Comment: I do not see anything so far tymeJV

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/21617685/215552 for how to debug ajax calls

Comment: oh, thanks Mike, Im going to work on that.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the fact that I am running the page on a Mamp local server

Comment: Now chrome is saying that this is an uncaught typeError:   if (z.isString(H) && "" !== H)       Says that it cannot read  'isString"  let me proceed with checking the AJAX, not sure what to replace 'isString' with

Comment: OK guys, I edited the post and put the ajax call at the bottom

Comment: @Orlando you can also use [jsbeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) for format your javascript code :)

Comment: @Mauricio but will that only beautify the code or fix the problem? Or are you thinking that fixing the format might fix the problem? Well Ill try and see.

Comment: A friend of mine told me that I need to 'check the XHR requests and see if it turns up any JSON, then take that and run it into an online JSON parser to check it'.