# Ajax,php,jquery,codeigniter post error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

in my project I need to post the data from view model to controller, but my AJAX post code is not working. Could you please help me in solving this problem?

My modal code which contains form in view:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_form">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <form action="#" method="post" id="form" role="form">
                    <legend>Form title</legend>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label >First Name</label>
                        <input name="firstname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Input field">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label >Last Name</label>
                        <input name="lastname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Input field">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label >gender</label>
                        <input name="gender" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Input field">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label >Address</label>
                        <textarea name="address" id="input" class="form-control" rows="3" required="required"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label >Dob</label>
                        <input name="dob" type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Input field">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" id="savebtn" onclick="save()" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

My ajax and jquery code to post the data to controller,

```
function save(){
    $('#savebtn').text('saving...');
    $('#savebtn').attr('disabled',true);


     $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo base_url('index.php/Crud/add_details')?>",
        type: "POST",
        data: $('#form').serialize(),
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data)
        {

            if(data.status) //if success close modal and reload ajax table
            {
                $('#modal_form').modal('hide');
                reload_table();
            }

            $('#savebtn').text('save'); //change button text
            $('#savebtn').attr('disabled',false); //set button enable 


        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert('Error adding / update data');
            $('#savebtn').text('save'); //change button text
            $('#savebtn').attr('disabled',false); //set button enable 

        }
    });
  }
```

Controller function

```
public function add_details() { 
  $data = array(
            'firstName' => $this->input->post('firstName'), 
            'lastName' => $this->input->post('lastName'), 
            'gender' => $this->input->post('gender'), 
            'address' => $this->input->post('address'), 
            'dob' => $this->input->post('dob'), 
          ); 

   $insert = $this->person->save($data); 
   echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE)); }
```

But it is not posting data to my controller. Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What kind of error(s) do you get?

Comment: Actually it not post any value to my controller,if i tried to print the $_POST in controller it will be empty.

Comment: But do you receive an error in your controller, is the success part executed or the error part from your ajax script

Comment: ya its display the error part in ajax code

Comment: Please paste your php code written in the function that is called here : `index.php/Crud/add_details`

Comment: Try hardcoding the url like http://example.com/index.php/... for a sec, I suspect that your PHP code cannot be executed

Comment: [The Network tab is immensely useful in actually debugging code.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21617685/2191572)

Comment: Also check in the source code whether your ajax URL is properly shown, also use firebug in firefox and go to console and check the ajax request there

Comment: public function add_details()
 {
  $data = array(
    'firstName' => $this->input->post('firstName'),
    'lastName' => $this->input->post('lastName'),
    'gender' => $this->input->post('gender'),
    'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
    'dob' => $this->input->post('dob'),
   );
  $insert = $this->person->save($data);
  echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
 }

Comment: Your code looks fine, can you try placing a `die("TESTING");` before $data var  to check if your function is getting called or not.

Comment: Also, `console.log(errorThrown)` will be informative.

Comment: it might be bad url issue /crud/add_details vs /index.php/crud/add_details, or htacces, or unavailable route.

Comment: i used the same url in from action /index.php/crud/add_details it works but in ajax call it not works.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://[::1]/ajax_crud/index.php/Crud/add_details. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.           This is the error i got in console

Answer (score -1):

> *WOW!! 9 months & No Answer Posted -  :| $-$ @_@*

Okay, it's CodeIgniter (& I love CodeIgniter), I can't let it Go..

***Wiki Start :D***

If your url working on browser (*you are doing GET request*) & not working with ***POST/AjaxPOST*** request and getting ***500/403*** Response/Status, It's means: ***YOU NEEDS To SEND CSRF TOKEN ALONG WITH POST/AjaxPOST***

If you are using ***CodeIgniter CSRF Protection*** `$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;` inside *`CodeIgniter/application/config.php`* ***YOU MUST BE  SEND CSRF TOKEN ALONG WITH POST/AjaxPOST***

> **You can use CSRF token inside your html form:**

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="form" role="form">
    <input type="hidden" name="<?=$this->security->get_csrf_token_name()?>" value="<?=$this->security->get_csrf_hash()?>">
    <!-- Your Other Stuff Waiting Here....  -->
</form>
```

or, using ***CodeIgniter built-in Form Helper*** (*Default method would be POST*)

```
<?=form_open('controller/action', 'id="ci_form_csrf" class="form-controller"'); ?>
    <!-- Your Other Stuff Waiting Here....  -->
<?=form_close();?>
```

If ***Not using CodeIgniter CSRF Protection*** `$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;` inside *`CodeIgniter/application/config.php`*

and..

> - *Url working with GET request*
> - *Url not working with POST request or AjaxPOST request*

*Check your Controller method, If you have any Request Check Condition or have Code for GET only..*

```
public function my_method () {
    if($this->input->get()){

    }
}
```

> - *Url not working with GET request*
> - *Url not working with POST request*
> - *Url working with AjaxPOST/AjaxGET request*

*Check your Controller method, If you have any Request Check Condition or have Code for AJAX only..*

```
public function my_method () {
    if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {

    }
}
```

- *Url not working with GET request*
- *Url not working with POST request*
- *Url not working with AjaxPOST/AjaxGET request .. and your OS or
  Server is LINUX/UNIX*

> ***Make sure you have Correct Naming Convention for CodeIgniter Controller & Model file*** 
>   : [**See CodeIgniter Change log**](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/changelog.html):

---

> ***Class file names now must be Ucfirst and everything else in lowercase***

---

*CodeIgniter Class Standard Naming:* ***Ucfirst_controller***, ***Ucfirst_model***...

> ***That means Every Class File must be Adhere The CodeIgniter Standard Naming Convention***

*Controller file name User.php or User_controller.php*

```
class User extends CI_Controller {}
```

*Correct access url:* ***http://www.website.com/controller/method/param***

**Model file name User_model.php**

```
class User_model extends CI_Model {}
```

*Correct way to load model in controller:* ***$this->load->model('User_model')***

> ***Wait... what about AjaxPOST :|***

*There is 2 Common approach to send CSRF token along with AjaxPOST*

1 - Use PHP Code inside inline JavaScript, ***$this->security->get_csrf_token_name()*** & ***$this->security->get_csrf_token_hash()***

2 - Define a JavaScript global var/object to store CSRF name & value & pass on later as calling JavaScript global variable.

3 - Add CSRF meta tag on top head html body and put token name and value there.

```
<meta id="CsrfSecrets" name="<?=$this->security->get_csrf_token_name()?>" content="<?=$this->security->get_csrf_hash()?>"/>
```

4 - Set CSRF token within in AjaxSetup,

```
// attach CSRF object for each AjaxPOST automatically
$.ajaxSetup({
  data: CsrfSecret
});
```

***OMG!! :/ It's so confusing for me.. do you have any example for me plzzzzzz.. :(***

*Hmmm.. no worry, I am giving you example to make you Happy :)*

***Example First - (CodeIgniter CSRF Demo | AjaxPOST)***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Using meta tag to retrive CodeIgniter CSRF token -->
    <meta name="<?=$this->security->get_csrf_token_name()?>" content="<?=$this->security->get_csrf_hash()?>"/>
    <title>CodeIgniter CSRF Demo | AjaxPOST</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Set CodeIgniter base_url in JavaScript var to use within
    var _BASE_URL_ = "<?=base_url()?>";
    var _CSRF_NAME_ = "<?=$this->security->get_csrf_token_name()?>";
    (function($) {
        // getting meta object from body head section by csrf name
        var CsrfMetaObj = $('meta[name="' + _CSRF_NAME_ + '"]'),
        CsrfSecret = {};
        // get meta tag name & value
        CsrfSecret[CsrfMetaObj.attr('name')] = CsrfMetaObj.attr('content');
            // attach CSRF object for each AjaxPOST automatically
            $.ajaxSetup({
                data: CsrfSecret
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="button">Click Me to Trigger AjaxPOST</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // on DOM ready
        $(document).ready(function(){
            // my button 
            $btn = $('.button');
            // on button click
            $btn.on('click', function(e){
                // stop default event
                e.preventDefault();
                // calling AjaxPOST
                $.ajax({
                    url: _BASE_URL_ + 'Controller/Method',
                    method: 'POST',
                    // or manually add csrf object
                    // data: $.extend({id:23, name:'scott'}, CsrfSecret); 
                    success: function(data){
                        alert('Success');
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error){
                        alert(error);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

***Example Two - (CodeIgniter CSRF Refresh  Demo | AjaxPOST)*** *`$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;`*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta id="CsrfSecrets" name="<?=$this->security->get_csrf_token_name()?>" content="<?=$this->security->get_csrf_hash()?>"/>
    <title>CodeIgniter Refresh CSRF Demo | AjaxPOST</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Set CodeIgniter base_url in JavaScript var to use within
    var _BASE_URL_ = "<?=base_url()?>";
    var _CSRF_NAME_ = "<?=$this->security->get_csrf_token_name()?>";
    (function($) {
        /**
         * New jQuery function to set/refresh CSRF token in Body & to attach AjaxPOST
         * @param  {[type]} $ [description]
         * @return {[type]}   [description]
         */
         $.fn.CsrfAjaxSet = function(CsrfObject) {
            // getting meta object from body head section by csrf name
            var CsrfMetaObj = $('meta[name="' + _CSRF_NAME_ + '"]'),
            CsrfSecret = {};
            // if CsrfObject not set/pass in function
            if (typeof CsrfObject == 'undefined') {
                // assign meta object in CsrfObject
                CsrfObject = CsrfMetaObj;
                // get meta tag name & value
                CsrfSecret[CsrfObject.attr('name')] = CsrfObject.attr('content');
            }
            // CsrfObject pass in function
            else {
                // get Csrf Token Name from JSON
                var CsrfName = Object.keys(CsrfObject);
                // set csrf token name & hash value in object
                CsrfSecret[CsrfName[0]] = CsrfObject[CsrfName[0]];
            }
            // attach CSRF object for each AjaxPOST automatically
            $.ajaxSetup({
                data: CsrfSecret
            });
        };
        /**
         * New jQuery function to get/refresh CSRF token from CodeIgniter
         * @param  {[type]} $ [description]
         * @return {[type]}   [description]
         */
         $.fn.CsrfAjaxGet = function() {
            return $.get(_BASE_URL_ + 'Csrfdata', function(CsrfJSON) {
                $(document).CsrfAjaxSet(CsrfJSON);
            }, 'JSON');            
        };
    })(jQuery);
    // On DOM ready attach CSRF within AjaxPOST
    $(document).CsrfAjaxSet();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button class="button">Click Me to Trigger AjaxPOST</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // on DOM ready
        $(document).ready(function(){
            // my button 
            $btn = $('.button');
            // on button click
            $btn.on('click', function(e){
                // stop default event
                e.preventDefault();
                // trigger refresh csrf token
                var CSRF = $(document).CsrfAjaxGet();
                // use callback to put your AjaxPOST & Done!
                CSRF.success(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: _BASE_URL_ + 'Controller/Method',
                        method: 'POST',
                        success: function(data){
                            alert('Success');
                        },
                        error: function(xhr, status, error){
                            alert(error);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```