# DataTables warning: table id=tableProduct - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, codeigniter-2

The same code and functionality is working properly on LOCALHOST without any error. But on my Online server i am getting above error message.
 so here is my code details
in controller this is the code:

public function listproduct(){

```
    $table = 'fc_products';
    $primaryKey = 'id';

    $columns = array(

        array( 'db' => 'code', 'dt' => 0 ),
        array( 'db' => 'name',  'dt' => 1 ),
        array( 'db' => 'category',   'dt' => 2 ),
        array( 'db' => 'description',     'dt' => 3 ),
        array( 'db' => 'tax',     'dt' => 4 ),
        array( 'db' => 'price',    'dt' => 5,
               'formatter' => function($d, $row ) {
                 return  $ret  = number_format((float)$d, $this->setting->decimals, '.', '').' '.$this->setting->currency;

               } 
        ),
        array( 'db' => 'photo',    'dt' => 6 ,
            'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
               $action ='<div class="btn-group">';
               $yesiam = label('yesiam');
               $areyousure = label('Areyousure');
               $viewproduct = label('Viewproduct');
               $edit = label('Edit');
               $modifyStock = label("ModifyStock");
               $viewImage = label("ViewImage");
               $printBarcodes = label('printBarcodes');

               $row_id  =   $row['id'];
               $row_color  =   $row['color'];
               $row_code  =   $row['code'];

              if($this->user->role === "admin"){

                 $action .="<a class=\"btn btn-default\" href=\"javascript:void(0)\" data-toggle=\"popover\" data-placement=\"left\"  data-html=\"true\" title='$areyousure' data-content=\"<a class= 'btn btn-danger' href='products/delete/{$row_id}'>$yesiam</a>\"><i class='fa fa-times'></i></a>";
              }
              $action .="<a class=\"btn btn-default\" href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick=\"Viewproduct($row_id)\"><i class=\"fa fa-file-text\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"top\" title=\"$viewproduct\"></i></a>";

              $action .="<a class=\"btn btn-default\" href=\"products/edit/$row_id\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"top\" title=\"$edit\"><i class=\"fa fa-pencil\"></i></a>";

              if($this->user->role === "admin"  && $row['type'] === 0 ){
                  $action .= "<a class=\"btn btn-default\" href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick=\"modifystock($row_id)\"><i class=\"fa fa-tasks\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"top\"  title='$modifyStock'></i></a>";
                  }

               if($d){ 
                   $action .= "<a class=\"btn $row_color white open-modalimage\" data-id=\"$d\" href=\"\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#ImageModal\"><i class=\"fa fa-picture-o\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"top\" title=\"$viewImage\"></i></a>";

               }

               $action .= "<a class=\"btn btn-default\" href=\"javascript:void(0)\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#barcode\" onclick=\"productBcode = $row_code\"><i class=\"fa fa-barcode\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"top\" title=\"$printBarcodes\"></i></a>";

              $action .= "</div>";

              /*$action = "<div class=\"btn-group\">
                   <a class=\"btn btn-default\" href=\"javascript:void(0)\" data-toggle=\"popover\" data-placement=\"left\" data-html=\"true\" title=\"\" data-content=\"<a class=&quot;btn btn-danger&quot; href=&quot;products/delete/11597&quot;>Yes, delete it!</a>\" data-original-title=\"Are you sure ?\"><i class=\"fa fa-times\"></i></a></div>";
              */
                  return $action;      
                }
        ),
        array( 'db' => 'color',     'dt' => 7 ),
        array( 'db' => 'id',     'dt' => 8 ),
        array( 'db' => 'type',     'dt' => 9 ),
    );

   $this->load->database();

    // SQL server connection information
    $sql_details = array(
        'user' => $this->db->username,
        'pass' => $this->db->password,
        'db'   => $this->db->database,
        'host' => $this->db->localhost
    );

    require( 'traits/ssp.class.php');
    echo json_encode(
        SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
    ); 
    exit();    
}
public function loadProducts(){

    $offset = $this->input->post('offset');
    $products = Product::find('all', array('limit'=>200,'offset'=>$offset));

    require( 'traits/load.php');
    exit();



    //$this->content_view = 'pos';
}
```

in js script :

```
var tableProduct = $('#tableProduct').DataTable( {
        'processing'    : true,
        'serverSide' : true,     
        'ajax' : 'index.php/products/listproduct',
        //'ajax' : "<?php echo site_url('products/listproduct')?>/",
        dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        tableTools: {
            "sSwfPath": "https://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.4/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
            'bProcessing'    : true,            
            "aButtons": [
                    "xls",
                    {
                        "sExtends": "pdf",
                        "sPdfOrientation": "landscape",
                        "sPdfMessage": ""
                    },
                    "print"
                ]   
         },
         drawCallback: function() {
            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
        }  
      });      

} );
```

Comment: Please use a easier to read Title and reformat your code at the end.

Comment: Check your console for the loaded JSON response and add it to your question please. That’s an error in you JSON response from the server.

Comment: [**Tutorial: How to debug AJAX calls**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21617685/2191572)