# Codeigniter Ajax gets 404 Error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I wrote an application on my local machine that works perfectly. I am using XAMPP so it is running Apache.

When I uploaded the application to my ubuntu test server, I am getting a 404 error on the ajax call and I am honestly perplexed.

I am using CodeIgniter 3.1.8.

The controller is definitely there and the .htaccess is working fine on my local machine. I checked the case of the filename for the controller and it is fine.

Here's the javascript of the ajax call:

```
function step2(){
    var canShow = false;    
    var cCode = $("#student_code").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/decide/ajaxStep2",
        data: {"student_code": cCode, "lang": "<?=$lang?>"},
        method: "post",
        success: function(data){
        }
    });
}
```

The controller definition and applicable function (just to show it exists... I don't think the internal code is relevant):

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Decide extends MY_Controller {
    function ajaxStep2(){
        //Code here
    }

}
```

I have done reading and I see some stuff related to the routes file but again I come back to the fact that it works fine on my local machine. I don't think it's file permissions because the index() method runs fine.

I have used ajax a lot and I have never had this issue before so I am honestly not sure where to even look on this. Any thoughts?

Comment: [**How to debug AJAX calls**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21617685/2191572)

Comment: Can you manually visit `http://my-test-ubuntu-server/decide/ajaxStep2` without a 404? There is nothing special about AJAX, it's just a behind-the-scenes web request.

Comment: Does your browser's web dev tool show the requested URL as being correct?

Comment: use base_url in ajax URL like   url : "<?=base_url('decide/ajaxStep2');?>"

Comment: MonkeyZeus: I get a 404 when I do it manually... I have checked it out. If I add /index.php/ to the url, it will work from the browser. So, it would seem the problem is the .htaccess file which works perfectly on my local machine. I have checked and the file permissions on the ubuntu are set to 755 on the .htaccess file and it is a standard codeigniter .htaccess file. I have also confirmed that rewrite is loaded so I am a little confused here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Use `base_url()` or `site_url()` in ajax like this :*

```
url: "<?=base_url('decide/ajaxStep2');?>",
```

OR

```
url: "<?=site_url('decide/ajaxStep2');?>",
```

Whole code should be like this

```
function step2()
{
   var canShow = false;    
   var cCode = $("#student_code").val();
   $.ajax({
      url: "<?=base_url('decide/ajaxStep2');?>",
      data: {"student_code": cCode, "lang": "<?=$lang?>"},
      method: "post",
      success: function(data){
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: I see the URL when the ajax is called and it is correct. I am looking at it in the Console and I see it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Could you change the uppercase S from step and try again as lower case url ? I think camel case is been replaced by your framework hope it helps

Comment: OK. This is weird. I changed everything to lowercase both in the controller and in the JavaScript. It worked once and then stopped (even on the one step that it worked...). I thought this did it but I am back to the drawing board.

Comment: Strange what else did you change on it ? Is the code on this question updated to the last piece ? Maybe replace the uppercase case letter with a dash following by the letter could work (guessing here) something like ```/ajax-step2``` let me know please :)

Comment: OK, thanks to some of the comments above I checked the url with a browser. It seems as if the rewrite instructions in the .htaccess are not working and I cannot figure out why. If I change the url to /index.php/decide/ajaxstep2 it works fine (which is what I have done for now).

Answer (score 0):

As you named your Controller class **Decide** the file name must be **Decide.php**. Your application will work perfectly on local XAMPP environment even though you named your file as decide.php but it won't work on a live server.

you have to put the capital letter in front of the file name to make them work. Windows has no problems at all since they don't use case-sensitive naming as Linux/Unix do. So as incredible, this can sound if your Windows XAMPP localhost server is working and when you upload it to a Linux/Unix XAMPP and you keep getting 404 errors, try the capital letter first, that could save you some time.