# AJAX form not submitting info to database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to make a contact form with AJAX that will send data to my database. However nothing is being recorded. Can someone help me find the error I'm making?

HTML - this is the code for the actual form

```
<form method="POST">
                    <fieldset>
                        <label>First name:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="firstName" id="fNameInput" required/>
                        <label>Last name:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lNameInput" required/>
                        <label>Email:</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="emailInput" required/>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                        <label>Subject:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="subject" id="subjectInput" />
                        <label>Message:</label>
                        <textarea name="message" id="msgInput" ></textarea>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                        <label>Your role:</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="role" value="writer" id="writerInput">Writer
                        <input type="radio" name="role" value="contributor" id="contribInput">Contributor
                        <input type="radio" name="role" value="administrator" id="adminInput">Administrator
                    </fieldset>
                    <input type="submit" value="Send" id="sendMsgBtn" />
                </form>
```

PHP - processing page (I don't think it's the processing page. It uploaded data to the db just fine before I tried updating my form to AJAX)

```
<?php

$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$interest = $_POST['interest'];
$role = $_POST['role'];

$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname= ;charset=utf8mb4";
$dbusername = " ";
$dbpassword = " ";

$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $dbusername, $dbpassword);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `contact` (`id`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `email`, `subject`, `message`, `interest`, `role`) VALUES (NULL, '$firstName', '$lastName', '$email', '$subject', '$message', '$interest', '$role'); ");

$stmt->execute();

?>
```

JS - script to submit content from database

```
var sendMsgBtn = document.getElementById("sendMsgBtn");
sendMsgBtn.addEventListener("click", addMsgFunction, false);

function addMsgFunction(e) {
    var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest; 
    myRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){     

        if(myRequest.readyState === 4){        
            //console.log(myRequest.responseText);// modify or populate html elements based on response.
            var responseObj = JSON.parse(myRequest.responseText);
            console.log(responseObj.success);
        } 
};

var fNameInput = document.getElementById("fNameInput");
var lNameInput = document.getElementById("lNameInput");
var emailInput = document.getElementById("emailInput");
var subjectInput = document.getElementById("subjectInput");
var msgInput = document.getElementById("msgInput");
var techInput = document.getElementById("techInput");
var indInput = document.getElementById("indInput");
var desInput = document.getElementById("desInput");
var writerInput = document.getElementById("writerInput");
var contribInput = document.getElementById("contribInput");
var adminInput = document.getElementById("adminInput");

myRequest.open("POST", "process-contact.php", true); //true means it is asynchronous // Send urls through the url
myRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

myRequest.send("firstName=" + fNameInput.value+
    "&lastName=" + lNameInput.value+
    "&email=" + emailInput.value+
    "&subject=" + subjectInput.value+
    "&message=" + msgInput.value+
    "&interest=" + techInput.value+
    "&interest=" + indInput.value+
    "&interest=" + desInput.value+
    "&role=" + writerInput.value+
    "&role=" + contribInput.value+
    "&role=" + adminInput.value); 
}
```

Comment: First things first, check your console for errors and check request's response for information. Secondly, why are you preparing yet passing variables directly, kinda defeats the purpose of preparing, no? Thirdly, you seem to be looking for a response in your JS yet you aren't passing any JSON back?

Comment: Use your browser's **development tools** to spy the HTTP requests to be sure they are well-formed.

Comment: Check out my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/21617685/2191572 for a rundown of how to debug AJAX calls.

Comment: I do not see you cancelling the submit button

Answer (score -2):

How about using jquery.. Give your form id="myForm" and submit button id="submit" Dont forget to include jquery file in your head

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:'your/php_file/path',
            data:$("#myForm input").serialize(),
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);  
            }
        });
    });
});
```