# How can I handle PHP sessions with the Fetch API?

Tags: php

I'm using the Fetch API in my JavaScript:

```
fetch('/api-url', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({ checked: event.currentTarget.checked }),
    mode: "same-origin",
    credentials: "same-origin",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Which posts to a PHP backend. However, when I call `session_start`, the script blows up. No error message, even with all error logging turned on and my error handlers disabled.

```
<?php
session_start();
echo('Hello, world!');
die;
```

It works fine with regular browser requests. I'm using PHP 7.2.9. I can see the session ID is passed in the request, so it looks like `Fetch` is doing everything correctly.

Comment: If you can show some sample PHP code used in `api-url`

Comment: I'm using the Aura package. But it happens just manually calling the function as well. I've added some code.

Comment: What do you mean it blows up? Check your PHP error logs and for your own sanity get cozy with the [network tab](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21617685/2191572) for debugging AJAX calls. While you're at it, check your console for JS errors.

Comment: calling `session_start` if the session is already started might cause an issue. so maybe `if(session_status()===PHP_SESSION_NONE){session_start();}`

Comment: Please elaborate on 'blows up'. Details matter

Comment: The script terminates and returns a 200 Success header with no body. There are no entries in the error logs.

Comment: @ChrisWorfolk i replicated and it was working fine with AJAX but with fetch the body was blank. But, once I added `.then(res => res.text())` to the chain it starts receiving body. Seems like chrome is omitting the response body while server is sending the data properly. Check the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I'll give you a working example to start with.

#### fetch-to.html (or *.php)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script>

        const data = { username: 'example' };

        fetch('fetch-from.php', {
            method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
        mode: "same-origin",
        credentials: "same-origin",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',  // sent request (alt: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
                'Accept':       'application/json'   // expected data sent back
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log('Success:', data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

#### fetch-from.php

```php
<?php

$contentType = isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"])
    ? trim($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"])
    : '';

if ($contentType !== "application/json") {

    $response = [
        'data'      => '',
        'errorCode' => '1',
        'errorText' => 'Incorrect contentType. Should be "application/json".'
    ];

} else {

  // Receive the RAW post data.
  $content = trim(file_get_contents("php://input"));

    // Decode data
  $decoded = json_decode($content, true);

  if (!is_array($decoded)) {
        // If json_decode failed, the JSON is invalid.
        $response = [
            'data'      => '',
            'errorCode' => '2',
            'errorText' => 'JSON invalid. Could not decode.'
        ];
  } else {
        // Do your magic
        $response = [
            'data'      => [
                'empty' => 'true',
            ],
            'errorCode' => '0',
            'errorText' => ''
        ];

        // For you example
        session_start();
        $response['data'] = $_SESSION;
  }
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

You may use `$decoded` as you would normally use `$_POST` with `$.ajax`.

Answer (score -3):

I replicated and it was working fine `with` AJAX but with `fetch` the body was blank. But, once I added `.then(res => res.text())` to the chain it starts receiving body. Seems like chrome is deleting the response body while server is sending the data properly.

```
fetch('/api-url', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({ checked: event.currentTarget.checked }),
    mode: "same-origin",
    credentials: "same-origin",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
}).then(res => res.text()).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Just pipe the response through a processor and it will work.

You can use `res.json()` to parse JSON.

Comment: No luck for me, unfortunately.