# Ajax keeps returning incorrect output from PHP

Tags: php, ajax

this codes keeps returning 0 even if the username and password I entered is correct. I also did try the php codes without ajax but it works perfectly.

PHP

```
include('config/connection.php');

if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']);

    $select_query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE username='$username' AND password ='$password'");
    $count_rows = mysqli_num_rows($select_query);

    if($count_rows > 0){
        echo "1";
    } else {
        echo "0";
    }
}
```

AJAX

```
    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'phpscripts/function/fnc_login.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            //if fnc_login.php returned 1/true
            //redirect to index page
            if (result == 1) {                 
                window.location = "index.php";

            //if fnc_login.php returned 0/false
            } else {
                $('#message').html('User not found!').fadeIn('slow');
            }
        }
      });
    });
    return false;
```

Comment: You are at risk of SQL Injection. Please consider switching to prepared statements.

Comment: What response does the AJAX event get? You should not use plain text passwords.

Comment: Get cozy with `console.log();` or else you're wasting your time. Try `console.log(result);` Here's how to debug AJAX: properly http://stackoverflow.com/a/21617685/2191572. Are you even sure that `form` has all of those POST fields that your PHP code needs? Refer to the network tab to see if you are sending the data that PHP needs.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: Open the browser's developer tools and check the request/response in the network tab of the tools.

Answer (score -2):

In your ajax success function, alert the result as so:

```
alert('-' + result + '-');
```

This will indicate the actual and complete response data received from the server. It's likely that your response contains a newline or perhaps some text that causes jquery to misunderstand the response datatype.

If the datatype appears wrong you can pass an explicit data type as so:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'phpscripts/function/fnc_login.php',
    dataType: 'text',
    data: $('form').serialize(),
```

Finally, once you know what the response looks like and you know it's 100% correct, compare it as a string, like so:

```
if (result == "1") { }
```

Comment: Please, [quit using `alert()` for troubleshooting.](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/), use `console.log()` instead.

Answer (score -3):

you check integer value in response not string

```
if (result == "1") { }
```

Hope it solve your problem.

Comment: `mysqli_num_rows` does the counting. https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: No need for count function it results in number of affected rows.

Comment: It still returns 0 as an output