# Linking php with postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql

I am trying to send the data from javascript to Postgresql using PHP however I am facing a problem. I don't know if my PHP connects to the Postgres at all. I get no errors or any changes in the database.

```
js function
function sendData(Firstname, Surname, Age) {

    const hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const url = "post.php";
    const data = "Firstname=" + Firstname + "&Surname=" + Surname + "&Age=" + Age;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    // Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    // Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
    hr.send(data); // Actually execute the request
}
window.onload = function () {
    sendData("rob", "roy", "23");
};
```

and post.php

```
<?php 

$First = pg_escape_string($_POST['Firstname']);
$Last =  pg_escape_string($_POST['Surname']);
$Age = pg_escape_string($_POST['Age']);

$host        = "host = localhost";
$port        = "port = 5432";
$dbname      = "dbname = postgres";
$credentials = "user = postgres password=root";

// Connecting, selecting database
$dbconn = pg_connect("$host $port $dbname $credentials")
if($dbconn){
    echo "Connected";
}
    else{
     die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());
    }
                        //tried only people doesn't work
$dbquery = "INSERT INTO public.people(Firstname, Surname, Age) VALUES('$First','$Last','$Age')";
$result = pg_query($dbconn, $dbquery);

       if (!$result) { 
            $errormessage = pg_last_error(); 
            echo "Error with query: " . $errormessage; 
            exit(); 
        }  
echo "Operation done successfully\n";
// Closing connection
pg_close($dbconn);
?>
```

[image: Database]

Comment: What do you get if you `var_dump($dbconn);`?  If you are _not_ getting connected, the first change I would suggest is removing the spaces in your strings like "host = localhost";

Comment: Hi i tried ```var_dump($dbconn);``` and removed spaces between strings still no response.

Comment: You also may want to consider using [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-prepare.php) so that you don't have to worry about quoting issues and SQL injection

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "no response"?  The `var_dump()` would always show you _something_.  Where are you _looking_ for the response?

Comment: I am using var_dump() just after declaring $dbconn. Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: Okay, but you didn't answer my question

Comment: Just so we on the same page, i need to look for var_dump() -> response in the console, right?

Comment: Yes.  You already claimed that you were getting no response though.  So that's why I asked where you were _looking_ for a response.  Were you not?

Comment: yes, i was but i didn't get using ```var_dump($dbconn)``` does that mean the connection is not established right?

Comment: As I said, `var_dump()` will always output _something_, even if it is `NULL`.  So if you are literally getting _no_ response, then you are either looking in the wrong place, or something is breaking your code _before_ that.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong btw im looking in firefox console also looked in chrome console.

Comment: [See Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21533285/why-the-ajax-script-is-not-running-on-iis-7-5-win-2008-r2-server/21617685#21617685).  Note that steps 4 and 5 should be adjusted for your specific case, but otherwise, that's how you should be looking for the response.

Comment: Thanks this was helpful. The data is been sent but its been blocked from somewhere. Timing tab in the firefox debugger shows waiting for a response.