# Facing this error "ValidationException: The parameter cannot be converted to a numeric value: NaN"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to enter the data in AWS Dynamo DB through the AWS Lambda function using AWS HTTP API. FYI The data type of the parameter (Id) originally in Dynamo DB is Number but it is taking as String while parsing JSON data, so I have written "Number" beside "Id" parameter in order to convert it to "Number". When I am trying to run this lambda function I am getting this error. Please help, Thanks!

Lambda function:

payload: { "Id": $input.json('$.Id') "name": $input.json('$.name')

```
console.log('starting function');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'us-east-1'});

exports.handler = function(event, ctx, callback) {

  var params = {
    Item: {
      Id: Number(event.Id),
      name: event.name
    },

    TableName: 'Test'
  };
  console.log(params)
  docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
    if(err) {
      callback(err, null);
    } else{
      callback(null, data);
    }
  });
  
}
```

Error log:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Look at the logs.

Your event.Id value is "NaN" which means "not a number".

Also event.name is "undefined".

So your problem is occuring here:

```
exports.handler = function(event, ctx, callback) {
```

Your event object is not populated with the values you are expecting.

The payload should be proper JSON and look something like:

```
 {
    "id": "6",
    "name": "Test Name"
 }
```

To achieve this, in your POST from your front-end code you could use something like:

data: `JSON.stringify({"id": $('#Id').val(), "name": $('#name').val()})`

Make sure that `$('#Id').val(`) and `$('#name').val(`) actually have proper values.

Comment: Thanks for the response but when I put hardcoded data, my data is able to get stored in Dynamo DB. So is that really a problem?  @JackMarchetti

Comment: Right. Your DynamoDB code is perfectly fine. It's your event object that is null or empty which is the problem. Can you provide the payload you're sending to your lambda?

Comment: Sure following is my payload, 

{
    "Id": $input.json('$.Id'),
    "name": $input.json('$.name')
}

Comment: I don't think that will show up as proper json. try sending something like:  
{
  "id": "6",
  "name": "Test Name"
 }

Comment: Tried to send the above payload as you mentioned it worked while testing the API on Postman (sent hardcoded data as same you mentioned above in payload)but still doesn't work when I try from the frontend.

Comment: what front end are you using?

Comment: The following link is what I am working on.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67491559/facing-issue-in-frontend-for-my-aws-lambda-function-which-will-be-storing-data?noredirect=1#comment119293422_67491559

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232309/discussion-between-shreyas-anil-chaudhari-and-jack-marchetti).