# Codeigniter 404 error on IIS7

Tags: codeigniter, iis-7, http-status-code-404

When I try to go to
    localhost/myproj/user
it gives me a 404 error, but when I type
    localhost/myproj/index.php/user
It works

How can I fix this? thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Codeigniter 2 on IIS with web.config file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408111/codeigniter-2-on-iis-with-web-config-file)

Comment: where can i find that web.config file ??