# Web Config file for a codeigniter application

Tags: php, codeigniter, iis, web-config

I am suffering with a web config file that is not rewrite the url for my codeigniter application. here is the web config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Clean URL" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

here is my site :
http://gandhitomodi.com

i am not able to get this kind of url
http://gandhitomodi.com/controller/method/

for example

http://gandhitomodi.com/welcome/index/

Please Help me through this.

****Edited*****

here is the route.php

```
$route['default_controller']="welcome/index";
$route['sendmail']="welcome/send";
```

here is the config.php settings that i have changed.

```
$config['base_url']="http://gandhitomodi.com/";
$config['index_page']='';
$config['url_protocal']='PATH_INFO';`
```

Comment: What kind of webserver do you use? Usually a .htaccess file is used. Why use XML?

Comment: @Clemenz it is a window iis 7.0 server not the apache that's why i have to use web.config.

Comment: Just a simple google result. Have you tried this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965124/how-to-rewrite-the-index-php-of-codeigniter-on-windows-azure

Seems you miss some RegEx in your config.

Comment: yes i have also tried that. @Clemenz

Comment: How about this? I have no knowledge of IIS. So i don't know if you have a management panel. http://phreek.org/blog/2010/06/codeigniter-url-rewriting-on-iis-7 (Note the last item, change your CodeIgniter config index_page setting!)

Comment: Post your config/router.php

Comment: @Goose i have added the route.php and config.php file.

Comment: @Clemenz i am not able to try that url because i have not the hosting details only ftp that i have.

Comment: Last try. I dont have any experience with IIS, so i cant help you further. I am actually googling for you. Something you can do too, so you wont need me haha. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408111/codeigniter-2-on-iis-with-web-config-file?rq=1 (its for CI 2 but maybe it will work, check out the comments too)

Comment: It's Ok dude @Clemenz i am searching it for almost 2 days and i am not getting the things done. that's why i have posted this question. and one more thing i have also tried the last before HA HA LOL.

Comment: Have you tried `<clear />`, It removes all rewrite rules for this application.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tries this method as mention here

> https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/04/23/converting-apache-htaccess-rules-to-iis-web-config-using-iis-manager-for-azure-websites/

also it is mention over here

> https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/09/28/convert-apache-htaccess-to-iis-web-config/

under the URL Rewriting section. It has the same .htaccess which I am using also there are many online converters to whom you can give a try

Answer (score 2):

For your config file, [try this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965124/how-to-rewrite-the-index-php-of-codeigniter-on-windows-azure). It appears that your issue is on your action line.

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
```

Change that to:

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
```

The question mark is causing your issue. Also, your match line might be changed to:

```
<match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
```

That is a bit more specific and might prevent some headaches later on.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
          </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

you can try this code it will work fine i am also using this code only

thank you

Answer (score 2):

I have also in problem when i was working with mssql and windows server and codeigniter platform. Its so hard for me to remove index.php from url or you can say pretty url . After a lot of disscussion and r&d. I got some changes in webcofig file at root of server.

Rewrite rule for web config to remove index.php is 
:

```
    ﻿<configuration>
    <appSettings>
         // default code..
    </appSettings>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <clear />
// another default code

 </handlers>
        <rewrite>
              <rules>
                <rule name="Rule" stopProcessing="true">
                  <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                  <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/favicon.ico$" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                  </conditions>
                  <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
              </rules>
            </rewrite> 
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Definately its working and also remaining part of codeigniter working fine. Also important thing set default url etc setting in routes.php and config.php . If any another help write your comment.

Answer (score 0):

First we will need to remove index.php from url

so in **route.php** you will change the line

```
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
$route['404_override'] = 'notfound';
```

and in **config.php** you will change the line

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

After that you will need to add **.htaccess** file in the root directory of website like this:

```
/application
/system
/assets
/.htaccess
```

and add this code to **.htaccess** file

```
Header append X-FRAME-OPTIONS "SAMEORIGIN"
Header set Cache-Control "no-store"
Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
ErrorDocument 403 /notfound.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L] 


<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
        # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
        # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
        # Submitted by: ollakalla

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

</IfModule>
```

Then you can access your method in controller like this example

```
class Reviews extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function latest()
    {
         // Some code here
    } 
}
```

by http://gandhitomodi.com/reviews/latest/

Comment: there is the main problem that i can't use the .htaccess hence it is a IIS Server not the Apache.